# How to upload a zip file on azure storage without location path?

Tags: c#, azure, windows-services, azure-blob-storage

I am uploading a zip file on azure storage with windows service using cloudblockblob which is working fine with upload stream. But when i check into azure storage explorer, it is appending the location path at the start of zip file name like this,

> C:\Users\bwadmin\Source\BusinessWorx\Connector Service
>   v5.1\TSS_03092016_635931219970817910_470088b2-9416-e411-ae0a-6c3be5a81b54_TSSCustomers.zip

while i just want the file name there like this,

> TSS_03092016_635931219970817910_470088b2-9416-e411-ae0a-6c3be5a81b54_TSSCustomers.zip

the code i am using is

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\" + zipfilename))
            {
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
            }
```

Any idea?

Comment: How are you creating an instance of block blob in your code? Please share that code.

Comment: this is how i am creating instance    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\" + zipfilename);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the following line of code:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly‌​.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\" + zipfilename);
```

to

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(zipfilename);
```

and that should take care of the problem.

Comment: o buddy You are great. It solved my problem :) thank u so much